# mockjax with Jquery post

Tags: jquery, ajax, mockjax

I have mockjax for auto complete and it is working great.I have no issue with mockjax and do not want to change it.

Here is its code

```
   $.mockjax({
    url: '*',
    responseTime: 2000,
    response: function (settings) {
        var query = settings.data.query,
            queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase(),
            re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi'),
            suggestions = $.grep(countriesArray, function (country) {
                 // return country.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
                return re.test(country.value);
            }),
            response = {
                query: query,
                suggestions: suggestions
            };

        this.responseText = JSON.stringify(response);
    }
});
```

Now on the same page i have to use jquery post which give me error

```
$.post("save.php", { id:id }, function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

It qive me error "query not define"

Please teach me how to use both on one page with out disturbing other?

Answer (score 1):

The object you are passing to `jQuery.post` does not have a `query` key, but you are trying to reference it in the first line of the mockjax response function: `settings.data.query`

Mockjax just passes whatever data you try to post with jQuery to the callback you specify.

See how this feature works in a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/gabor_nagy/N4x2Z/